# Excel Drop Down lists for range of years

Tags: excel, dropdown

Hello I want to create conditional drop down lists and I am stuck on how to proceed. What I plan to do is for the user to select the range of years based on which further things will be displayed in tables below.My date range is from 2008 to 2020.

[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJpXI.jpg)

So if the user selects 2015, the following drop down list must show only 2016 to 2020.

I tried putting in a IF statement in the data validation link but that is not working. I also tried making named lists but im not able to use them in an IF statement in the data validation source.

[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5AyD.jpg)

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example:

[image]

I have the following name definitions:

[image]

My Excel is a German one. So in English Excel the manager is called `Name Manager` and the formulas in Refers To will be:

`YearFrom`: `=Sheet1!$B$3`

`YearListFull`:  `=Sheet1!$E$1:$E$13`

`YearListPart`:

```
=INDEX(YearListFull,MATCH(YearFrom,YearListFull,0)+1):INDEX(YearListFull,COUNT(YearListFull))
```

`YearListFull` is used as List in Data Validation for `B3`.

`YearListPart` is used as List in Data Validation for `B4`.

Comment: That was awesome! Thank you so much!!

Comment: For anyone else interested, I found another way to do this, but this method is much much better! http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/data-validation-dependent-lists-using-name-lists/d7d76ca7-d6c1-4803-bb0f-9da3a30d52b3?auth=1